# How to achieve 3D animation and reveal from this Google Wear demo?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

In [this animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBD0VlcVS1E&t=16m50s) from Google I/O on Google Wear, the "send" airplane icon animates in 3D and reveals the next screen.

How can I approximate this animation on a floating action button?

[image: Send animation]